# Trying to separate dev stage image from prod stage build using mult-stage building

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

**Well**, there's this **Node.js** app that I built using **Typescript + ExpressJS**, and now I'm trying to setup docker to have both a working development container and a production one.

**I'd** like to have only one **Dockerfile** in order to use the multi-stage building process.

**My** project consists of the root folder, inside of it there are all these dockerfile and compose files, and also my package.json, **src/** folder, yarn.lock and etc.

For now I have this:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.18.1-alpine3.14 as base
ENV APP=/app
WORKDIR $APP
COPY . $APP/
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile &&\
    rm -rf "$(yarn cache dir)"
RUN yarn build

FROM base as prod
ENV APP=/home/node/app
WORKDIR $APP
RUN chown node:node $APP
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node --from=base ./app/dist/ $APP/dist/
COPY --chown=node:node package.json yarn.lock $APP/
RUN NODE_ENV=production yarn install --frozen-lockfile &&\
    rm -rf "$(yarn cache dir)"
```

If I build the base stage only, this is the image I get:
[image: dev image]

355.65 MB of image size.
Now if I check how big the `node_modules` inside the image is, this is:
[image: dev node modules]
That's ok for a dev node_modules.
Checking the layers with `dive`, I get these:
[image: dive dev]
You can see that 237 MB of those 355 is the node_modules folder.

**Now, the production part.**
If I build to the `prod` target of the dockerfile, that's my image size:
[image: prod image]
That's even bigger than the dev one.
Checking the node_modules size inside of that image:
[image: prod node]
Wen from 237 to only 36 MB, really good
But now if I check the layers from that image, that's the result:
[image: prod layers]
The 237 MB node_modules is still there, that's almost the entire image size. How can I avoid having that thresh in my production image? Without that, the result image should be something like 80 MB only, really better than 391.

Please, help me with that!!!

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/trying-to-separate-dev-stage-image-from-prod-stage-build-using-mult-stage-building/117579

Comment: It seems like you're asking a half-dozen different questions about this setup; can you break them up into separate SO questions?  Can you use plain Node without Docker for day-to-day development, avoiding the middle block of questions?

Comment: Hey, sorry for that, I'm gonna rewrite the question with only the most important thing I'd like to have help :D

Comment: hey @DavidMaze, done, I remade my question, it seems clearer. I got some info in my post on docker forums, but nothing that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fixed the problem by replacing `FROM base as prod` by `FROM node:14.18.1-alpine3.14 as prod`. The first method was caching all the base layers in the final build.